# ¿Como ejecutar .blur() de un input creado dinamicamente, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen dia.
El contenido dinamico lo creo de la siguiente forma

```
var listado_ofertas_adicionales = $('.listado_ofertas_adicionales');
                       valCarrito = response.data;
 $.each(valCarrito, function (i) {
        $('<li/>').addClass('swipeout')
              .append($('<div/>').addClass('swipeout-content item-content')
                      .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-media')
                    .append('<img src="' + valCarrito[i].Url + '" onerror="this.onerror=null;" alt="" width="40" height="60" />'))
                      .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-inner')
                      .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-title-row')
                      .append($('<div style="font-size: 12px;"/>').addClass('item-title').append(valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + " - " + valCarrito[i].Descripcion))
                     .append('<div class="codInventario" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + '</div>')
                      .append('<div class="tipo" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Tipo + '</div>')
                    .append('<div class="tipo_costo" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].TipoCosto + '</div>')
                    .append('<div class="precioSocio" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</div>')
                     .append('<div class="volumenNegocio" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].VolumenNegocio + '</div>')
                     .append('<div class="item-after" data-unit-price="' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '"><span class="product-amount" style="font-size: 12px;">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</span></div>')
                                        )
                   .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-text')
                  .append('<input type="number" class="add_ofertas_adicionales" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad">')                                             
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                .appendTo(listado_ofertas_adicionales);
                        });
```

El input donde quiero ejecutar la funcion es `class="add_ofertas_adicionales"`

Intente realizarlo de esta forma:

```
    $$('.listado_ofertas_adicionales').blur('.add_ofertas_adicionales',function(e){
console.log("Agregando producto oferta");
});
```

pero tal caso no me funciona. 
Revisando en la consola, veo que ese input me lo genera con una clase extra que yo no ingrese `not-empty-state`.

```
<input type="number" class="add_ofertas_adicionales not-empty-state" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad">
```

De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que has puesto lo que haces es registrar un controlador para el evento blur sobre todos los elementos que tengan la clase listado_ofertas_adicionales no add_ofertas_adicionales

```
$('.listado_ofertas_adicionales').blur()
```

Lo que debes es poner el blur sobre la clase que te interesa:

```
$('.add_ofertas_adicionales').blur(function(...))
```

La otra clase adicional que aparece no importa

Comment: Tampoco me funciona de esa forma compañero.

Comment: Entiendo que añades el controlador del evento blur después de crear los elementos con esa clase, no antes, y ¿no te ejecuta la función que tienes como controlador? Actualiza el post con el código, por favor

Comment: Correcto, es despues de crear los elementos que debo ejecutar una funcion con el evento .blur(), pues en los elementos que se crean van esos inputs.

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma solucione el problema:

```
$('.listado_ofertas_adicionales').on('blur','.add_ofertas_adicionales',function(e){
        console.log("Agregando producto oferta");
    });
```